# 422 Returned with "password cannot be blank" Rails 4.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I have a controller for my users:

```
class API::V1::UsersController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :json

  def create
    @user = User.create(user_params)
    respond_with(:api, :v1, @user)
  end
end`
```

I'm using the responders gem.

When I run my RSpec tests, I get a 422 error. Here is the failing test:

```
describe "POST create" do
  it "should create a user" do
    post :create, user: FactoryGirl.build(:user).attributes, format: :json
    expect(response.status).to eq(201)
  end
end
```

- I'm using has_secure_password on my user model.
- I have password and password_confirmation in my user_params (strong parameters)
- My factory has matching password and password_confirmation

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    first_name Faker::Name.first_name
    last_name Faker::Name.last_name
    email Faker::Internet.safe_email
    password "123456789"
    password_confirmation "123456789"
    date_of_birth 25.years.ago
  end
end
```

Anything I'm missing or should look for?

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to set devise mappings in spec/support/rails_helper.rb

```
@request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:admin]
```

See more at [devise wiki](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Test-controllers-with-Rails-3-and-4-(and-RSpec)#mappings)